# how to extract date only from the creation/modified date of a file?

Tags: shell, unix

Let's say the file name is : filetest.txt
and is present in the directory: inventory/data
How can I get the date at which this file was last modified/created?

Example : let's say if the file is created on 3rd June 2007 then it should return only value 3.

That means, how to extract the date only from that timestamp of file?

Comment: check it on "https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451554/stat-output-format-truncate-a-date-field". Try this `stat -c '%y' inventory/data/filetest.txt | grep -oP "(?<=-)\d+(?= )"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the date command to extract the modification time of a file by passing it as reference.

`date -r filename` prints the last modified timestamp of the file.

> Sat Jul  3 16:03:53 IST 2021

`date +%d -r filename` print just the day you asked for, but with a leading zero.

> 03

`date +%-d -r filename` prints the day, without a leading zero.

> 3